# How to build dynamic clothing-based web-site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

For comparison: something like the shirt builder application at www.blank[dash]label.com

Say, if I have fabric image and want to generate base, collar, cuff etc. How should I do it on server side in .NET, and generate different components of shirt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't generate the images on the server.

I would model the shirt in my favorite 3D modelling program, then apply the fabric image as a texture and pre-render all shirt parts for each cloth. Then I would just fetch the appropriate pre-rendered images when the user selects a new fabric.

The pre-render would be a manual step (with a script or completely manual) as a part of the process of adding a new fabric to the store.